# R.layout.main cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

I've found this code from Raghav Sood's Pro Android Augmented Reality book. I've tried to execute the code as it is written in the book but yet i am facing so much of difficulties.i've tried cleaning and building of project. Put the checkbox tick in the project's property dialogue box. Checked import Android.R presence in my code. Even i uninstalled my AndroidSDK and reinstalled it with different set of Android versions and APIs. Uninstalled and reinstalled Eclipse.

Here is my ProAndroidAR3Activity.java file

```
    package com.paar.ch3widgetoverlay;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ProAndroidAR3Activity extends Activity{
SurfaceView cameraPreview;
SurfaceHolder previewHolder;
Camera camera;
boolean inPreview;

final static String TAG = "PAAR";   
SensorManager sensorManager;

int orientationSensor;
float headingAngle;
float pitchAngle;
float rollAngle;

int accelerometerSensor;
float xAxis;
float yAxis;
float zAxis;

LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude;
double longitude;
double altitude;

TextView xAxisValue;
TextView yAxisValue;
TextView zAxisValue;
TextView headingValue;
TextView pitchValue;
TextView rollValue;
TextView altitudeValue;
TextView latitudeValue;
TextView longitudeValue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); //here is the problem. every part of the code with       R. is having problem


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 2, locationListener);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    orientationSensor = Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION;
    accelerometerSensor = Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(orientationSensor), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(accelerometerSensor), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    inPreview = false;

    cameraPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    previewHolder = cameraPreview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    xAxisValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xAxisValue);
    yAxisValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yAxisValue);
    zAxisValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zAxisValue);
    headingValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headingValue);
    pitchValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pitchValue);
    rollValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollValue);
    altitudeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altitudeValue);
    longitudeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitudeValue);
    latitudeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeValue);
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml file of my project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paar.ch3widgetoverlay"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ProAndroidAR3Activity" 
        android:screenOrientation = "landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges = "keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    </manifest>
```

The following is the res/layout/main.xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xAxisLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/xAxis" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yAxisLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/xAxisLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/xAxisLabel"
    android:text="@string/yAxis" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zAxisLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yAxisLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/yAxisLabel"
    android:text="@string/zAxis" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headingLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zAxisLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zAxisLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/heading" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pitchLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/headingLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headingLabel"
    android:text="@string/pitch" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rollLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pitchLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pitchLabel"
    android:text="@string/roll" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latitudeLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rollLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rollLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:text="@string/latitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitudeLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/latitudeLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/latitudeLabel"
    android:text="@string/longitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/altitudeLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/longitudeLabel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/longitudeLabel"
    android:text="@string/altitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xAxisValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/xAxisLabel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/longitudeLabel"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/yAxisValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/yAxisLabel"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/yAxisLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/xAxisValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zAxisValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/headingLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yAxisValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headingValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/headingLabel"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/headingLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zAxisValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pitchValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pitchLabel"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pitchLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/headingValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rollValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/latitudeLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pitchValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latitudeValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latitudeLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rollValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitudeValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/longitudeLabel"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/longitudeLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/latitudeValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/altitudeValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/altitudeLabel"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/altitudeLabel"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/longitudeValue"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

    </RelativeLayout>`
```

The following is the res/values/strings.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, ProAndroidAR3Activity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Pro Android AR 3 Widget Overlay</string>
    <string name="xAxis">X Axis:</string>
    <string name="yAxis">Y Axis:</string>
<string name="zAxis">Z Axis:</string>
<string name="heading">Heading:</string>
<string name="pitch">Pitch:</string>
<string name="roll">Roll:</string>
<string name="altitude">Altitude:</string>
<string name="longitude">Longitude:</string>
<string name="latitude">Latitude:</string>
<string name="empty"></string>
    </resources>
```

I have set the minsdk version to be 2.1 that is API 7 and the compile SDK version is 4.1 that is API 16...

please help me out...

Comment: An error in an XML file can prevent the R file from being built. If you are using Eclipse, open the Package Explorer window and look for any files in your `res/` folder with a red `x`.

Comment: </RelativeLayout>` there's an extra character after closing tag. Are you seeing an error on xml editor after saving main.xml on Eclipse?

Comment: My guess is that as that code is in a book it's probably outdated, maybe you need another sdk.

Comment: @harism no there is no error in xml file. it is showing error in the .java file

Comment: @jonathan.cruz book had took android 2.1 in its case. Shall i've to use the same?

Comment: Yea i think that would be best as there are minor but also major changes between sdks. At least start of that sdk and then test the newer.

Comment: The same problem again arises...

Once when i cleaned the project abd build it again the R.java file got away and again that R.layout.main error is getting displayed.

Comment: Do you have the R.java file in the gen folder? I would just start a new project and rebuild it bit by bit. Copy paste code doesnt really work well usually.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your properly generated fresh R.java class under the "gen" folder in Eclipse (/gen/[yourpackage]/R.java)?
If it is in the same package as your activity, you do not need to import it manually!

It should be there if the XMLs are correct! If there is a syntax error in the XMLs, then Eclipse will not genereate the R.java.

Besieds, there is a strange '`' character at the end of your layout file, I don't know if it is accident in your post, but this can be a problem:

```
</RelativeLayout>`
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: that ' character has been put down accidentally.

Comment: now the error is coming that cameraPreview cannot be resolved or is not a field. and the same error with zAxisvalue, xAxisValue and so on

Comment: The same problem again arises...

Once when i cleaned the project abd build it again the R.java file got away and again that R.layout.main error is getting displayed.

Answer (score 1):

(Expanding on user1649030's post because this is too big to be a comment:)

OK, there are generally two causes for the 'R not found' error.  One is an error in any of your xml files which cause R.java to not build at all.  Look under your 'gen' directory for R.java.  If not found, then that's your problem.  Look for bad xml files.

If R.java *is* being built, note what the directory path to it is.  This will match the package name specified in your manifest.  In your case, it would be gen/com/paar/ch3widgetoverlay/R.java.

This class is implicitly imported by all source files in your src/com/paar/ch3widgetoverlay/

Any source files in any other directory which need to access R will need to explicitly import com.paar.ch3widgetoverlay.R

That should pretty much cover it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import *your* R class from java, not Android's. If you import android.R it will cause conflicts. The R class is generated and may or may not be in the same package as ch3widgetoverlay especially if you got the code from a tutorial. Look in the gen folder in eclipse to find out what package the R class is in.

Comment: @Sam yes it is if the package defined in the manifest is not the same package as his ch3widgetoverlay. Besides he said he was importing "Android.R" which is the incorrect class to begin with and it would cause conflicts.

Comment: I don't see where the author is importing Android's R file and the package names are the same... (I agree there would be conflicts if the author did either of these things).

Comment: That's because you're trying to use cameraPreview without declaring it anywhere. You might want to get a firmer grasp on Java programming in general before you jump in with an example like this..

Comment: I see it declared: `SurfaceView cameraPreview;` (first line in the class) and it is initialized before being used: `cameraPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);`.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel I'll take care of it.

Comment: @Sam sure enough. Didn't see it

Comment: But is'nt cameraPreview has been declared in res/layout/main.xml file under the surfaceview???

Actually i am a newbee to android app..

Comment: @Samuel so where to initialize it????

and the same error is coming with the yAxisValue, zAxisValue....

Comment: There should be no problem with those variables nor cameraPreview as @Sam pointed out. Maybe you're missing a semi-colon somewhere

Comment: I am unable to find the missing semicolon..
i've been trying to debug this code from last 2 days but....
lets give it an another try

Comment: The same problem again arises...

Once when i cleaned the project abd build it again the R.java file got away and again that R.layout.main error is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing com.paar.ch3widgetoverlay.R